# Python: How to group 2 different values into one and reassign a new value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I Would like to seek help.
How to group 2 values into one and reassign a new name and also a new value to them?
Let's say A & B are a pair and C & D are a pair

Assuming that I have a df

```
Code Item Quantity
0001 A    1.5
0001 B    2
0001 C    2.5
0001 D    3
0002 A    1.5
0002 C    2.5
0003 B    2
0003 D    3
0004 C    2.5
0004 D    3
0005 A    1.5
0005 B    2
```

I want to make it become

```
Code Item Quantity
0001 AB   3
0001 CD   4
0002 A    1.5
0002 C    2.5
0003 B    2
0003 D    3
0004 CD   4
0005 AB   3
```

Any Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: how do you define that A/B and C/D are pairs? How do you compute the new value?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming defined pairs, and that the new values is the sum, you can use:

```
pairs = {'A': 'B', 'C': 'D'}

group = df['Item'].map(pairs).fillna(df['Item'])

out = (df
 .groupby(['Code', group])
 .agg({'Item': ''.join, 'Quantity': 'sum'})
 .droplevel(1).reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
   Code Item  Quantity
0     1   AB       3.5
1     1   CD       5.5
2     2    A       1.5
3     2    C       2.5
4     3    B       2.0
5     3    D       3.0
6     4   CD       5.5
7     5   AB       3.5
```

For a generic way to group by sets of any size:

```
groups = [{'A', 'B'}, {'C', 'D'}]
mapper = {k:v for v,s in enumerate(pairs) for k in s}
group = df['Item'].map(mapper).fillna(df['Item'])
```